# Resize an Ubuntu partition without losing data

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed VirtualBox and an Ubuntu on my Windows machine. But after a while I needed more disk space, the problem is that my dev/sda1 partition (where I need more space) should be resized. Resizing it with the Ubuntu installation wizard will erase all the data (I have an Apache server, MySQL, etc... on it !).
My question: is it possible to resize the partition without losing the data ?
Or at least is it possible to restore it after the resizing ?

Answer (score 1):

Boot from live Linux distro and use gparted. Don't forget to make a backup incase something goes wrong. [More info.](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)